# PHP: How do I call all methods of the same name in a class hierarchy?

Tags: php, inheritance

I have a class hierarchy like the following:

```
class Alpha {
    public function initialize() {
        $class = get_class($this);
        $family = array( $class );
        while( ($class = get_parent_class($class)) !== false ) {
            $family[] = $class;
        }
        $family = array_reverse($family);
        foreach($family as $className) {
            // call $className's start (instance) method
        }
    }

    public function start() {
        echo "calling start from Alpha\n";
    }
}

class Beta extends Alpha {
    public function start() {
        echo "calling start from Beta\n";
    }
}

class Charlie extends Beta {
    public function start() {
        echo "calling start from Charlie\n";
    }
}

$c = new Charlie();
$c->initialize();
```

Alpha's initialize method should call the derived class's start method as well as all of the derived class's ancestor classes' start methods all the way back to Alpha's start method.  The code should produce the following output:

```
calling start from Alpha
calling start from Beta
calling start from Charlie
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to call an instance method of a specific ancestor class specified by the $className variable.

I've used `call_user_func(array($className, 'start'))` but this causes the start method to be treated like a static function.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are these three classes related?

Comment: I can't see any hierarchy at all...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `parent::start()`?  That's kinda how "hierarchy" works.  Also, in your example, the three classes are just three separate classes, there's no "hierarchy" here.

Comment: Pretty sure, you can't do this without `parent::start()`.  `Alpha` doesn't know what classes extend from it, and I don't think you can query that.

Comment: Thanks Sergey for understanding what I meant and not what I wrote :).  Sorry folks, I updated the question.  The reason I want to avoid parent::start() is because I would have to use it in all of the classes.  I'm looking for code that I only need in the base class that will call all of the derived classes' start methods.  I could potentially have a Delta, Elephant, Foxtrot, etc. class as well.

Comment: @Rocket: I updated the question to demonstrate how you can get an array of all the derived class names.

Comment: It gets all the classes that 'Charlie' extends, not all of the classes that 'Alpha' extends.  If you run the code above and `print_r($family)` you'll find that it does work.  `get_class($this)` returns the class name that `$this` was instantiated as (in this case 'Charlie').  Calling `get_parent_class($class)` returns 'Beta', and if `get_parent_class()` is called on a variable containing 'Beta', it will return 'Alpha'.

Comment: A parent should not be aware of its descendants; the only assertion you can make based on above code is that whenever a class `Alpha` is required, you can substitute it with `Beta` or `Charlie`. Try to think of another implementation.

Comment: I agree that a parent should not be aware of specific descendants, but it can still be aware that it _has_ descendants and act on them generically if they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class function call like Classname::start should call Classname's function start not static call

```
class Alpha {

    public $myvar = 0;

    public function initialize() {

        $class = get_class($this);
        $family = array( $class );
        while( ($class = get_parent_class($class)) !== false ) {
            $family[] = $class;
            $this->myvar ++;
        }
        $family = array_reverse($family);
        foreach($family as $className) {
            // call $className's start method
            eval("{$className}::start();");
        }
    }

    public function start() {
        echo "{$this->myvar} calling start from Alpha\n";
    }
}

class Beta extends Alpha {
    public function start() {
        echo "{$this->myvar} calling start from Beta\n";
    }
}

class Charlie extends Beta {
    public function start() {
        echo "{$this->myvar} calling start from Charlie\n";
    }
}

$c = new Charlie();
$c->initialize();
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?  The `'::'` calls the method statically, which is the same as `call_user_func(array($className, 'start'))`, which he doesn't want.

Comment: This does work.  While I generally try to avoid using eval(), if I can't find another solution that allows me to call the start methods as instance methods, I will probably resort to this.

Comment: @threed: This solution is *exactly* the same as `call_user_func(array($className, 'start'))`, (or `call_user_func($className.'::start')`)which you said you didn't want to do.

Comment: @Sergey: The string being passed to `eval` is `Beta::start();`.  That's a static call, it's different from `parent::start()`.

Comment: @Rocket, Try execute it and see {$this->myvar} in output for proof. If Beta is parent of this class it call not static function

Comment: @Rocket, I think it is: calling a function with the exact parent class

Comment: Perhaps this will help (though it's a bit confusing) [http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).  The `::` operator does not always indicate a static reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Alpha {
    public function initialize() {
        // ... call all 'start' methods in class hierarchy starting with highest level     class (Alpha's start method) and ending with lowest derived class
    }

    public function start() {
        echo "calling start from Alpha\n";
    }
}

class Beta extends Alpha {
    public function start() {
        echo "calling start from Beta\n";
        parent::start();
    }
}

class Charlie extends Beta {
    public function start() {
        echo "calling start from Charlie\n";
        parent::start();
    }

    public function initialize() {
        $this->start();
    }
}

$c = new Charlie();
$c->initialize();
```

Comment: One of the requirements is that Alpha's initialize method should do the calling of all the start methods.